# R Selenium / Docker WebServer to Download file from Interactive Website

Tags: selenium, docker, xpath, web-scraping, remote-server

I am trying to webscrape some chess games from the website chess.com using R Selenium. The idea would be to double click in the website, using the Docker remote server.

The link in the example leads to this [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8boJv.jpg).
Clicking on the download icon then leads to a [popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYa9P.png), from which we can download the chess PGN file.

The code I have so far is this:

```
link <- "https://www.chess.com/live/game/2"

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(link)

# Find Search tab, input search keys and initiate search

download <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                               value = '//*[@id="chess-board-sidebar"]/div[5]/div[2]/span/a[1]')

download$clickElement()
```

I also tried the alternative last step

```
download$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. It gives me the error message:

> Selenium message:Element is not currently visible and so may not be
>   interacted with Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1',
>   time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03' System info: host: '8d400ae06ea3', ip:
>   '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '4.14.104-boot2docker', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown
>
> Error:     Summary: ElementNotVisible      Detail: An element command
>   could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.
>      class: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException   Further
>   Details: run errorDetails method

I have tried scouting for solutions, but I can't find a way forward. I would appreciate a lot any solutions or suggestions!

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. It was a problem of outdated remote server with docker. Now that I am running with the new version (3.141.59) , it works fine:

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59-iron
```